# EMC Celerra and Access-based Enumeration

Tags: windows, cifs, emc, celerra

I have a few CIFS shares for Windows on our Celerra, and I've run the EMCABE tool (in enable mode) on one of our CIFS virtual servers. When I check if ABE is enabled using the same tool, it comes back working, however in practice, I can still see the folders that I shouldn't have access to, on all Windows clients. Admittedly you can't get in there, but is there something I'm missing? Or does it just plain not work right on the Celerra?

Answer (score -1):

I am not aware of EMCABE tool, but you can connect to NAS CIFS server(NAS server I mean), just like a regular computer and apply windows security permissions from there. It has worked very well for us till now.

Also browsing to the share and setting security permissions works.
If you are talking to .etc or hidden EMC folders, we generally create a share inside main mount point and share that out instead of the root share.

Comment: File permissions are already setup using the default Windows tools. ABE hides folders that you don't have permission to. I'm looking to hide folders from people, something that the ABE tools let you do in Windows Server 2003 R2 and on.